# Could bind() take a port that was configured in IPTABLES as forwarding port

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, bind

I have a gateway with linux firmware based system.

I have an `iptables` rule which allow to forward the port 8080 to a local host.

I m developing an application for this linux gateway.
this application will choose a random port between 8000 and 8100. And then it will make `bind()` on this random port.

Does `bind()` return OK if the random port is 8080. and then the application could start a listening server on the port 8080?

I do not want to make conflict with `iptables` rules.
So if the `bind()` return NOK then I can retry to choose another random port and then retry the bind.

Comment: forwarding exists independently of binding. if no process has bound to a port, then that port is available for binding, even if any traffic to/from that port has been forwarded elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcB Are there a way to find out all the port used in the iptables forwarding with C?

Comment: iptables has to be able to read out its own internal rules table, so probably there is an api/interface to get that kind of data, somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` returns ok and it does not check any firewall rules. There are several good reasons that `bind()` ignores firewall rules.

- The `bind()` is much older than iptables and it is a POSIX compliant call. Checking iptables could break backward compatibility.
- Iptables rules might be quite complex and it is difficult to decide whether the `bind()` has a meaning. There could be complex mangling rules, rules assigned to various physical and logical interfaces...
- Even if one can be sure that the `bind()` to a specific port has no meaning no, rules may change in near future and the bound port may become useful.
- ...

Well it is possible to read iptables rules via C interface like `libiptc` but it is not recommended:

> As has been pointed out numerous times on the mailinglist(s), libiptc
>   was *NEVER* meant to be used as a public interface. We don't guarantee
>   a stable interface, and it is planned to remove it in the next
>   incarnation of linux packet filtering. libiptc is way too low-layer to
>   be used reasonably anyway.
>
> We are well aware that there is a fundamental lack for such an API,
>   and we are working on improving that situation. Until then, it is
>   recommended to either use system() or open a pipe into stdin of
>   iptables-restore. The latter will give you a way better performance.